# C# script in html not reading the file

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, visual-studio

I'm trying to get a file which has a server name to be read by a htmnl (with a c# script to do the reading) but I cant get the script to pass the name to the html, this is the code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage3.master" Title="Services" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server">
    <center>
        <script runat="server">
            string[] server = new string[] { };
            void Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                string[] server = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\server.txt");  //here i get the name of the server
         return server[1];
            }
        </script>
        <br />
        <table width="600px" style="border-color: Silver; border-style: solid; border: 1">
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: LightBlue; text-align: center">
                    <a href="Default.aspx?SERVER=1">1</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: LightBlue; text-align: center">
                    <a href="Default.aspx?SERVER=2">2</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="background-color: LightBlue; text-align: center">
                    <a href='Default.aspx?SERVER=' <%#server[1]%>>JD5PKF1</a>
                </td>
                //but i cant get it to be read here
            </tr>
            <input type="button" value="All in one" onclick="location.href='Option2.aspx';">
        </table>
    </center>
</asp:Content>
```

any ideas?

Comment: I don't see anything here that is even attempting to pass the server name in. What exception are you getting? What methods have you tried to get the name into the html side?

Comment: A `<center>` tag? That's deprecated. Use CSS.

Comment: yeah i forgot to add the return when i posted this, basically it returned server[1]; (which i know that has something in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the errors others reported, the tag

```
<a href='Default.aspx?SERVER='<%#server[1]%>>
```

is malformed, as it should read

```
<a href='<%# "Default.aspx?SERVER=" + server[1] %>'>
```

AND it does not check whether server[] actually has an element at index=1.

Comment: well that change did help, but still it doent get read, i change the code so i hardcoded the server name to the script (basically i said server='server1', and return server;
but still it doent read it

Comment: found the error (at least for when its hardcoded) i was calling the variable when i should call the method

Answer (score 1):

Your website doesn't have access to your hard drive. If you want to open a file, you must place it inside the directory that is accessible (for instance place it under same directory as your website)

Answer (score 1):

You've declared server twice.

The first one you are not using.
The second you fill with text and then it goes out of scope.

It's hard to tell what your intent is.

Comment: if i dont define it it doesnt take the script as c#